# Why this program involving Java lock does not terminate?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to understand interruptible locks in Java.

I came across code which involved interruptible lock:

```
public class ReenterantLockInterruptbly {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
            Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
                int i = 0;
                System.out.println("before entering ReentrankLock block");
                try {
                    lock.lockInterruptibly();
                        while (0 < 1) {
                            System.out.println("in the ReentrankLock block counting: " + i++);
                        }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.println("ReentrankLock block interrupted");
                }
            });
            lock.lock(); // lock first to make the lock in the thread "waiting" and then interruptible
            thread.start();
            thread.interrupt();
    }
}
```

This printed:

```
before entering ReentrankLock block
ReentrankLock block interrupted
```

The program then terminated.

I feel I understand the reason for the output.
Next I decided to replace interruptible lock with uninterruptible/normal lock:

```
public class ReenterantLockInterruptbly {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
            Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
                int i = 0;
                System.out.println("before entering ReentrankLock block");
                try {
                    lock.lock();
                        while (0 < 1) {
                            System.out.println("in the ReentrankLock block counting: " + i++);
                        }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("ReentrankLock block interrupted");
                }
            });
            lock.lock(); // lock first to make the lock in the thread "waiting" and then interruptible
            thread.start();
            thread.interrupt();
            System.out.println("Main thread called thread.interrupt()");
    }
}
```

It printed:

```
Main thread called thread.interrupt()
before entering ReentrankLock block
```

The program then did not terminate. I did not understand why?

**Q1.** Is it because new / child thread is not able obtain lock which was not released by main thread, neither it is holding interruptible lock in order for it to get interrupted out of `lock()` as requested by main thread?

**Q2.** So child thread is stuck in wait set of `lock`, whereas main thread is executed to completion and terminated. Is it so?

**Q3.** If answer to 2 is yes, shouldnt completion and termination of main thread also terminate child thread too?

Comment: Q1: Yes. Q2: Yes. Q3: No,the other thread is not a [deamon](https://download.java.net/java/GA/jdk14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#setDaemon%28boolean%29).

Comment: I tried doing `setDaemon(true)` before starting thread and the code terminated. So it worked as you said. Just small doubt, the doc says " The Java Virtual Machine exits when the only threads running are all daemon threads.". So for every daemon thread a new VM is created letting main thread's VM exit?

Comment: Continuing doubt in above comment, I just tried debugging both code with and without child thread as daemon. With child as non-daemon, after running everything, debugger gets stuck with child thread in Debug window. With child as daemon, after running everything, Debug window gets disconnected from code execution, it does not show child running as daemon. Does daemon child still run after termination of main thread, but is not shown in Debug window? Or Termination of main thread also terminates child daemon and hence not shown in debug window?

Comment: After `main()` finishes, the the only thread running is the child thread. What do you guess does the VM if only deamon threads are running?

Comment: Doc of `Thread.setDaemon()` says VM exits if only daemon thread are running. So I VM must be terminating. But I am confused about what eclipse Debug window is showing. When child is daemon and main thread is still running, debug window shows both main and child thread, but when main terminates, it shows no thread running, even child daemon disappears. So, I was guessing whats going on.